# Why two examples' output are different about Javascript Boolean?

Tags: javascript

eg1:

```
 var boo = new Boolean(false)
 document.write(boo.valueOf())//false
```

eg2:

```
 var boo1 = new Boolean(new Boolean(false))
 document.write(boo1.valueOf())//true
```

Why two examples'  output are different?

By the way:

```
console.log((new Boolean( new Boolean(false))))//nothing
document.write(new Boolean( new Boolean(false)))//true
```

Why is there nothing in the console?

Comment: Just don't ever use `new Boolean` and you won't have to worry about it - why not just use literal booleans instead?

Comment: Why would you ever use `new Boolean`? And why the additional nonsense of `new Boolean(new Boolean)`?

Comment: There _is_ something in the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects are truthy, and when you use `new Boolean`, you're calling the Boolean *constructor*, which returns an object. When `new Boolean` is called with a truthy value, it results in a object whose value is `true`. Thus, `new Boolean(new Boolean(<anything>))` will result in a Boolean with a value of `true`.

But just don't do this - use literal booleans or `Boolean(condition)` instead.

Comment: Another, why is the output of  'console.log((new Boolean( new Boolean(false))))'  nothing? I think it will output "{}" in the console.

Comment: For me, it outputs `Boolean {true}`; `__proto__:Boolean[[PrimitiveValue]]: true` https://jsfiddle.net/r3qared0/

Comment: ok, thanks. My chrome did not work well. I can get same result as you in normal Chrome.